# Iframe height not adjusting with javascript in newer versions of Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I have an Iframe that links to another html page. The iframe is contained within a div. I found some code that would auto adjust the high depending on the contents of the iframe. This code works fine in firefox and older versions of internet explorer but its not adjusting the height in v7 or later.....

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function changeContent(){ 
        document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = window.frames['contentFRAME'].document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML; 
    } 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fl" id="right">
    <iframe class="newsFrame" id = "contentFRAME" name = "contentFRAME" src ="news.html" onLoad = "changeContent()"></iframe>
</div>
```

Can anyone help.....

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Comment: Is it legal in HTML to put spaces around the `=` in attribute definition ? Can you remove them ?

Comment: That code is not adjusting the height of the iframe, it is replacing the content in the page. Why don't you just use the XMLHttpRequest object to start out?

Comment: I should probably tell you I have very little knowledge of javascript. The degree I done they replaced the javascript module with RAD so never studied it. Im creating the website for my friends parents.

Comment: @dystroy - Removed the spaces but no changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function resizePanel() {
    window.console.log("ran the resize panel function");
    var frame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    if(frame != null) {
        frame.style.height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
}
```